# How to change color of a react icon on hover of a card in styled component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled components to built a react app. I am trying to switch color of icon and svg on hover of ServicesCardItem.

This is my JSX.

```
<ServicesCardItem>
                <IconBox1>
                  <svg
                    // width="100"
                    height="100"
                    viewBox="0 0 600 600"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke="none"
                      stroke-width="0"
                      fill="#f5f5f5"
                      d="M300,521.0016835830174C376.1290562159157,517.8887921683347,466.0731472004068,529.7835943286574,510.70327084640275,468.03025145048787C554.3714126377745,407.6079735673963,508.03601936045806,328.9844924480964,491.2728898941984,256.3432110539036C474.5976632858925,184.082847569629,479.9380746630129,96.60480741107993,416.23090153303,58.64404602377083C348.86323505073057,18.502131276798302,261.93793281208167,40.57373210992963,193.5410806939664,78.93577620505333C130.42746243093433,114.334589627462,98.30271207620316,179.96522072025542,76.75703585869454,249.04625023123273C51.97151888228291,328.5150500222984,13.704378332031375,421.85034740162234,66.52175969318436,486.19268352777647C119.04800174914682,550.1803526380478,217.28368757567262,524.383925680826,300,521.0016835830174"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                  <i>
                    <BsDribbble />
                  </i>
                </IconBox1>
                <h4>
                  <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </h4>
                <p>
                  Voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas
                  molestias excepturi
                </p>
              </ServicesCardItem>
```

> this is the styled component...

```
export const ServicesCardItem = styled.div`
  width: 32%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 20px 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  @media (max-width: 769px) {
    width: 48%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 426px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(252 248 248 / 58%);
  &:hover {
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 5px rgb(255 255 255 / 61%);
    path {
      fill: blue;
    }
    i {
      color: red;
    }
  }
  h4 {
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
export const IconBox1 = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #47aeff;
  position: relative;
  i {
    font-size: 36px;
    position: absolute;
  }
`;
```

Here is the image of that card.

[image]